# What should be used for drawing musical notes in an android layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-custom-view

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to make a sight reading (reading sheet music) training app for android to learn while doing it, but I'm not sure how I would make the drawing of the note and the staff.

Should I create a custom view? I'm guessing SVGs would be a part of this, but I'm kind of lost.
I'm using android studio.

I want something similar to this image (from another app):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to [create a view class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) and use the `drawPath()` function to draw the complex shapes and other drawing functions for the simpler shapes.

Note: There are other languages and tools which seem to make the process simpler (like flutter) but I'm not looking forward to learn those.